How does this logic function work correctly?
I am studying SystemVerilog from the book "Digital Circuit Engineering and
computer architecture".
There is a task.
Write a structure module to evaluate logic
functions y=ab~ + b~c~ + a~bc using multiplexer logic.
What is the difference between ~a and a~?
How to understand the notation ab~?

That notation makes no sense.  They are apparently using ~ as a postfix operator, but I've never seen any language that uses it as anything other than a prefix operator.

When they write the equation
y=ab~ + b~c~ + a~bc

That is not Verilog syntax, it is a sum of products. The ~ following variable name is instead of writing an overline on top of the variable name. In Boolean algebra, that overline means the negation of th value. Overlines are difficult to type in most editors, but i'm surprised to see they did not use it in a technical textbook.
The equivalent Verilog syntax would be (assuming a, b, and c are all single bit variables):
y= a && !b || !b && !c || !a && b && c

